# Access ComboBox to TextBox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a Tasks tabulated form that contains a combobox for the priority listing of the task.  The combobox has the row source tied to a Priority table.  I have the combo box working so it displays the correct text of "Urgent, High, etc." based on the Task and Priority tables relationship.

What I would like to do is instead of a combobox for the displayed priority I'd like it to be a textbox.  This is where I have problems.

How can I do this for a tabulated form and/or which fields do I need to change to accomplish this?

I have tried settings the textbox:

- `Control Sources = [Priority]![Priorities]` this gives #Error in the
  textbox
- `Default Value = [Priority]![Priorities]` this also gives #Error in
  the textbox
- `Control Source = DLookUp("[Priorities]","[Priority]","[ID]="&[Tasks]![Priority])` this gives #Name? in the textbox
- `Default Value = DLookUp("[Priorities]","[Priority]","[ID]="&[Tasks]![Priority])` this also gives #Name? in the textbox
- `Control Source = Priority` gives the number lookup for the relationship between the Tasks and Priority tables

This one works but it is noticeably slow.  Is there are "faster", better, way of doing this.

- `Control Source =DLookUp("Priorities","Priority","ID=" & [Priority])`

Comment: You may have to rename your textbox.

Comment: Is your priority table called 'Priority' or 'Priorities'?  If the latter, then you'll need to change your dlookup to `DLookUp("[Priority]","[Priorities]","[ID]=" & [Priority])`  This also assumes the priority ID is numeric - if it's text you'll need to put "'" in the dlookup to account for it being a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want a textbox? Still need a combobox to select the priority.

Is the form bound to Task table? Cannot reference the Priority table in the textbox Control Source or Default Value. A DLookup will not work in Default Value. DLookup in the Control Source should work.

Simpler approach is to set form Record Source to an SQL statement with left or right join that will 'include all records from Task and only those from Priority that match'. Bind textbox to the descriptive Priorities field from Priority. Set the textbox as Enabled No and Locked Yes so users cannot edit it.

If purpose is to mask/hide the ID then set the combobox as multi-column pulling the required fields with its RowSource SQL and hide the ID column by setting its width to 0. Or don't save the Priority ID, save the actual descriptive value. With very short descriptors and/or small databases that can be justified.

Comment: I think the OP is ultimately looking to mask the primary/foreign keys.  I agree your approach would be the simplest way.  The alternative would be to dlookup each value every time the record changes, which is incredibly wasteful and invokes tremendous delays with large recordsets.

Comment: See revised answer above.

Comment: The textbox is preferred because the tabulated form isn't to be editable by the user, only see the information.  I have a button on the side for editing the information.  The for is bound to the Task table.  I got the DLookUp working on the Control Source, but there is a pretty decent lag for populating the textbox.  Is that were you talk about changing the record source?  If so where do I find that option?

Comment: Form in design view, set its RecordSource property to an SQL statement as described. Double click the ellipsis (...) to open query designer.

Comment: Ok.  I got the RecordResource changed to have the query with join and it works great.  Thanks all.